# MongoDb Tailable Streaming Returns Duplicates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, angularjs, socket.io

I have a few `MongoDb Capped Collections` and I'm attempting to stream new entries (from another process) out to my page over `SocketIO` like so:

Server side:

```
...
var TickerSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
    bid : { type : Number },
    ask : { type : Number },
    mid : { type : Number },
    last_price : { type : Number },
    timestamp : { type : Date }
}, { capped: { size: 5242880, max: 1000, autoIndexId: true }});

var tickerStream = Ticker.find().tailable().stream();

ioserver.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    clientsocket = socket;

    tickerStream.on('data', function (doc) {    
        clientsocket.emit('ticker', doc);
    }).on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('error: '+err);
    }).on('close', function () {
      // the stream is closed
      system.debug('close');
    });
...
```

Client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');

  function TickerController($scope, $http, $window)
  {
    $scope.ticker = null;

    $scope.init = function(){

    }

    $window.socket.on('ticker', function(ticker){
      console.log(ticker);
      $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.ticker = ticker;
      });
    });

  }
```

But when I run the app, I get the new events, but I get 2-3 of them instead of just 1 new document being inserted.

I've checked the collection and it doesn't have the duplicates - I do have *multiple channels on the same socket* could this be the issue?

[image]

Comment: take out $scope.$apply and try.

Comment: this items aren't getting update on the page when I don't use the `$scope.$apply` I don't think let me look

Comment: ok ... attempted it ... no change, except the items aren't appearing on the page (in the `JADE` template) and their are still duplicate documents in the `console.log` statements.